# I2S on STM32F446ZE micro controller to check(test) microsemi ZL38063

Tags: audio-streaming, stm32, microchip

Here I am trying to generate a simple example of sine wave to pass over I2S and just send the data on ZL38063(slave) using STM32F446ZE . 
Clock is working fine @1.5Mhz and WS @48Khz and also getting PWM data on SD line.
I am not able to hear any kind of sound on speaker connected with ZL38063.
Here I am unable to debug further. 
PS below simple c code

```
 HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2S2_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_DAC_Init();
  MX_UART5_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_SDIO_SD_Init();
  MX_FATFS_Init();

HAL_I2S_Init(&hi2s2);
  uint16_t test = 0;

        int index = 0;

        bool channel = false;
      while(1) {

        if (HAL_I2S_GetState(&hi2s2) == HAL_I2S_STATE_READY)
            {
                hal_res = 
                     HAL_I2S_Transmit(&hi2s2,&SINE_TABLE[index],256,50);

                channel = !channel;
                if (channel)
                {
                    index++;
                    index = index % 256;
                }

            }
        else
        {
            test = 5;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Isolate the problem, go from there. Does communication with ZL38063 work? What commands are you sending? Have you got an oscilloscope? Schematic and self-contained compilable source code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Hi @domen I have seen waveform of I2S on oscilloscope. I got signals on SD,WS and CLK lines of I2S. These lines are connected with ZL38063 board , but not getting any sine wave on output side DAC (we have put a speaker)of audio processor.SO how can i debug further?

Comment: Hi @domen please answer

Comment: My first comment is still valid. What have you done since then? Update the post with new info please.

Comment: @domen Step 1). I will load Audio DSP firmware using it's PC application.
                Step 2). I will Configure I2S for STM32 micro controller and generate 
                sine wave of 1khz.
                Step 3). Expecting output from Audio DSP to play ton on speaker 
                which i am not getting..